# Caching in Asp.net (slidingExpiration and absoluteExpiration)

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

hy,

How can use `absoluteExpiration` and `slidingExpiration` , if i specify both of them i get 
:absoluteExpiration must be DateTime.MaxValue or slidingExpiration must be timeSpan.Zero.

```
Cache.Insert("cachetest", value, Nothing,  ??,??;
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

For sliding expiration, use this:

```
Cache.Insert(key, value, Nothing,
             Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
```

For absolute expiration, use this:

```
Cache.Insert(key, value, Nothing,
             DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration)
```

Comment: what do you put in "key", "value"?

Comment: Cache.Insert(key...) will this overwrite an existing key? or will that throw an exception?

Comment: @TamarG "key" is an identifier you wish to use for this cache item. "value" is the item/ value you wish to store in the cache

Comment: I know it's an old answer, but you should be using DateTime.UtcNow when dealing with cache.

Answer (score 1):

You must use one or the other. From the Microsoft documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05kd8d77.aspx

> absoluteExpiration
>
> ... If you are using absolute expiration, the slidingExpiration parameter must be NoSlidingExpiration.
>
> slidingExpiration
>
> ...If you are using sliding expiration, the absoluteExpiration parameter must be NoAbsoluteExpiration.